# ZF2 MVC global function

Tags: php, inheritance, zend-framework2

**What is best practice for making a function/method global to the application for several controllers?**

For example lets say we have a controller. This controller is using a function, but instead of copy pasting it to another controller, we just want to make a call to that function.

```php
class ControllerName extends AbstractActionController {
    // Your actions

    // Has to become a call,
    // instead of copy pasting this function to several controllers
    public function GlobalFunction ($parameter) {
        //Use parameter and return something
    }
}
```

Creating `ControllerPlugins` is one solution, I've also read about creating and setting up a `StdLib`. So what is the best practice for a function which will only be called at the controllers?

### Two other related questions:

The plugin that is described in the accepted answer will do the job. But in what case you do NOT want to use a plugin and will go for another solution? I just want to brighten it up, since I did not find enough documentation about it.

Another point of interrest. What if this plugin has to be available to several modules aswell? Setting up the plugin within the application and setting it up in the `module\Application\Config\module.config.php` or within the `Config\Autoload\Global.php` of theZend App?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want to look at the several [`Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/Plugin)-Classes provided. Ultimately it all depends on what your "global function" is supposed to do. It may either be suited to do it as a ControllerPlugin or it may better be suited as a functionality provided by one of your Services.

To write your own ControllerPlugin, do it like the following:

```
namespace Yournamespace\Controller\Plugin;
 
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;
 
class YourPlugin extends AbstractPlugin
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Register your plugin at configuration, either inside `getConfig()` with the top-level-array-key or inside your Modules `getControllerPluginConfig()` without the top-level:

```
'controller_plugins' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'yourPlugin' => 'Yournamespace\Controller\Plugin\YourPlugin',
    )
),
```

And simply use it:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $plugin = $this->yourPlugin();
    $plugin->doSomething();

    return new ViewModel();
}
```

If you just want to call `$this->yourPlugin($paramX, $paramY)`, then you have to define a `__invoke()` method to your ControllerPlugin.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot @Sam, I kinda asked this question since I didn't find the ZF2 manual that clear about defining global functions. It's about what's best practice in which situation. For the above example the plugin will do the job. But in what case you do NOT want to use a plugin and will go for another solution? I just want to brighten it up, since I did not find enough documentation about it.

Comment: Ultimately you can make everything available as a plugin. However once the logic behind becomes too complex, better write a Service for that and have the plugin interact with the Service. It always depends on what occasions you need the functionality. If you're 100% certain you only need it inside your controllers, just write a plugin. But if it's needed ANYWHERE ELSE, write a Service. You can then add a plugin that interacts with the Service.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Namespace\Controller\Plugin\MyPlugin::getServiceLocator()

Comment: @Sam Thanks a lot.. It helped a lot. is there something similar to this by which I can keep a part of my html common for all pages(like a sidebar) and populate it dynamically ?