# zend framework 2 query from plugin

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

How can i query from zend-framework plugin?
I used this code in creating plugin: [ZF2 MVC global function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438275/zf2-mvc-global-function/16438454#16438454?newreg=fb38446a8a0843028d9358c0dd617911)

Here is my current code in my plugin:

```
namespace Users\Controller\Plugin;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Session\Container as SessionContainer;
use Zend\Session\Container;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;

class MenuPlugin extends AbstractPlugin
{
    protected $permissionsTable;

    public function availableLinks($theController = '', $modules = '')
    {
        $moduleId       = 0;
        foreach ($modules as $row) {
            $moduleId = $row->id;
        }
        $session_user   = new Container('user');
        $roleId         = $session_user->user_data['roleId'];
        $the_functions  = $this->getPermissionsTable()->getAvailableFunctions($moduleId,$roleId);
        return $the_functions; 
    }

    public function getPermissionsTable()
    {
        if (!$this->permissionsTable) 
        {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->permissionsTable = $sm->get('Users\Model\PermissionsTable');
        }
        return $this->permissionsTable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call $this->getServiceLocator()->getServiceLocator(); in order to get the main service manager. When you call $this->getServiceLocator() you just get the plugin manager. And you should also implement ServiceLocatorAwareInterface so that the system injects the plugin manager into your plugin object. All in all, your code should look something like this:

```
//...
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

class MenuPlugin extends AbstractPlugin implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{ 

    use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

    protected $permissionsTable;

    public function availableLinks($theController = '', $modules = '')
    {
        $moduleId       = 0;
        foreach ($modules as $row) {
            $moduleId = $row->id;
        }
        $session_user   = new Container('user');
        $roleId         = $session_user->user_data['roleId'];
        $the_functions  = $this->getPermissionsTable()->getAvailableFunctions($moduleId,$roleId);
        return $the_functions; 
    }

    public function getPermissionsTable()
    {
        if (!$this->permissionsTable) 
        {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator()->getServiceLocator();
            $this->permissionsTable = $sm->get('Users\Model\PermissionsTable');
        }
        return $this->permissionsTable;
    }
}
```

However, I your PHP version doesn't support traits then add the following code to your class:

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface

private $serviceLocator;

public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
{
    $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
}

public function getServiceLocator()
{
    return $this->serviceLocator;
}
```

Comment: Can you please check your error logs and provide more specific error message?

Comment: it says:
Fatal error: Interface 'Users\Controller\Plugin\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface' not found in /webapps/JerickAlita/new_cms/module/Users/src/Users/Controller/Plugin/MenuPlugin.php

Comment: Please include:  use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface

Comment: what about the ServiceLocatorAwareTrait?